# How to achieve multi tenancy in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have to deploy an application on cloud which should support multi-tenancy.
The application should have authentication of users and display the customized UI on the basis of user.
I want to understand how Kubernetes or Kubernetes for GCP supports kubernetes.

I have tried to search of relevant material on internet.

Comment: I think there needs to be a bit more detail of the use-case. Are you referring to multi-tenancy from within the application-level or multi-application? If it is the latter, you can deploy the application to different "namespaces" in Kubernetes for additional isolation.

Comment: Per the above, then you'd need to provide ingress per deployed application / namespace pairing.  E.g., you'd either need some sort of router/controller infrastructure, if making it transparent to the user, or provide separate ingress endpoints / URLs per namespace.  You'd still want to filter out someone hitting the "wrong" URL by providing authorization checks within the application.

Comment: @MrSaints - Thanks for your response. Here as our use case is multi-tenancy in the application-level. We want to deploy an application on cloud ( Preferably on Kubernetes ) which should support multi-Tenancy for different customers. Can you please provide inputs on the best approaches to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

kubernetes is a container orchestration engine that helps you deploy a container/pod, scaling, rolling upgrade, rollback etc.

application authentication and custom UI for different users needs to be handled in the application code. We have implemented similar functionality using angularjs frontend with postgreSQL as backend.
The app runs fine in kubernetes cluster.

Comment: @P Ekambaram - Thanks for your response. Could you please share your thoughts on the best practices to be followed to achieve multi-tenancy at application level.